# UserData Script is not executing on Amazon Ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data

i am facing some problem with userdata execution on windows AMI, trying to execute the userdata like, opening notepad start notepad.exe i had tried to execute this its not working,this script is getting copied to instance but when i tried to connect to instance the notepad didn't open..Any one had faced the similar problem?

Comment: Are you trying to use userdata to run a script when you connect to the instance? If so that is not what userdata is for.

Comment: No, we are not trying to run it when we connect to the instance. If the script would've started the notepad then it must be found open there.

Answer (score 0):

Userdata is only used when an instance is launched for the first time. It can be used to configure or run process on your instances when you first launch it. This is useful if you have a lot of instances you need to setup at once.

Userdata scripts do not run when you connect, but you could use it to add scripts to windows startup.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,i am using userdata script first time while i am creating new instance and in this first i am downloading the setup.exe from s3 bucket,then installing it and finally starting that setup.exe using start setup.exe command.every thing from starting like downloading from S3 and installing is working fine.but last step start setup.exe is not working,when i connect to instance..according to your answer it seems that if i didnt connect to instance then this start setup.exe will work or not..??

Comment: Does setup.exe require a user session to run? Can it run an install silently in the background?

Comment: In that case running from userdata probably wont work. When user data runs, there is no user session running at that time.